# Couldn't able to find buit-in function $PMTargetName@numAffectedRows

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange

Hi Iam novice to Informatica, I tried to get the count of inserted rows to target  to WF variable, So that I can write a condition to a link to proceed to next session.

I went through few web guides and found **$PMTargetName@numAppliedRows**.
But I didn't able to find this property under Built-in properties in Post session on success variable assignment.

Even I tried to assign a variable in mapping level with this property, but I am getting error like Invalid symbol reference.

Answer (score 1):

$PMTargetName@numAppliedRows is NOT listed anywhere among any variables. Neither in built-in nor anywhere else. Still - you can use it. Just remember to replace the `TargetName` with the name of your target transformation, e.g.: if you insert data to AccountList table, you'd need to use the condition `$PMAccountList@numAppliedRows`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this link workflow variable :-

- Name:     TgtSuccessRows
- Desciption:   Rows successfully loaded
- Datatype:     integer

But issue is you can not track data loaded for multiple targets.

Comment: Thanks for reply..But I would like to know to apply on multiple instance having sessions. It would be appreciable by sharing any possible ways